# ContentDocument / ContentVersion's SharingPrivacy acceptable values

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument

According to the [ContentVersion documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) under `SharingPrivacy`, it mentions:

> Controls sharing privacy for a file. Only administrators and file owners with Collaborator access to the file can modify this field. Default is `Visible to Anyone With Record Access`. When set to `Private on Records`, the file is private on records but can be shared selectively with others.

But when I query a sample record, I see "N" as the values.

Is there a list of all the acceptable values, and what they actual mean / map to?

Comment: The accepted answer below applies for ContentVersion and ContentDocument. Both objects have  the same gap in the documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can utilize workbench to view the details of the field. It's a picklist field with the values as below.

> label: Visible to Anyone With Record Access
>
> value: N
>
> label: Private on Records
>
> value: P

Comment: This is gold - didn't realize I could use Workbench in that capacity.  Thank you!