# Content version error 'bad value for restricted picklist'

Tags: contentversion

I'm trying to write a simple trigger to change the picklist value 'SharingPrivacy' on 'Content Version' object when a new attachment is uploaded but I'm getting error 'bad value for restricted picklist'.

```
trigger test on ContentVersion (Before Insert) {
for(ContentVersion opp: trigger.new){
opp.SharingPrivacy  = 'Private on Records';}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **API** value, not the **display** value. If you check the docs, you'll the options are `N` and `P`. See also [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/262168/2984). The value you're looking for is "P".

```
opp.SharingPrivacy  = 'P';
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much @sfdcfox. It works as expected but I'm wondering where can I find the list of API names because I also want to change the value on the 'SharingOption' field to  'Freeze Sharing Off' so no one can further share this file. Sorry to be a pain but I'm new to programming so it would be really helpful if you can also help me build Apex Class please so that I can migrate this Trigger into production. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Inniboy In most cases, the documentation has the appropriate values. ContentVersion is one of those odd cases. I actually just tend to use the tried and true method of describing the field: `sObjectField field = ContentVersion.SharingPrivacy; /* change this */ for(PicklistEntry value: field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) { System.debug(value.getValue()+': '+value.getLabel()); }` You can run that in Developer Console > Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window.

Comment: and also above trigger should only apply for people with certain profiles (example when profile A and profile B uploads any documents then the trigger should kick in). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Inniboy (just saw your edit). As for writing an Apex Class, are you asking about a unit test? Trigger framework? Something else?

Comment: sorry for being so naive. My understanding is after I've got a trigger written in SB I'll also need an Apex class to migrate it into production, so I was referring to that Apex class unless you can suggest a different way to migrate the code into production.

Comment: @Inniboy yes, you need a [unit test for your trigger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers). Check out the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103284/discussion-between-inniboy-and-sfdcfox).